# Why does ClickHouse not support ON CLUSTER option for MATERIALIZED views?

Tags: clickhouse

I have checked the [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/view) and the option is supported for  normal views but not for materialized views.

I read around a bit and noticed people are saying that materialized views act locally. That is, they are supposed to read data from local tables and insert into local tables for performance reasons. This is understandable, However, I don't understand why the `ON CLUSTER` options is omitted from the creation query. `ON CLUSTER` creates the view on all nodes of a cluster with a single command rather than having to do it on each node individually. Is there a reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/view#materialized-view) you point to says that `ON CLUSTER` is supported:

`CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW [IF NOT EXISTS] [db.]table_name [ON CLUSTER] [TO[db.]name] [ENGINE = engine] [POPULATE] AS SELECT ...`

What makes you think it is not?

Comment: My mistake! It turns out I put the `ON CLUSTER` after the `TO` clause which is why I received an error. Should I delete the question?